# comparing/intersecting compare criteria

Tags: oop, comparison, criteria

If there's any open source code that does this already I'm interested in hearing about it. But I haven't seen it yet so I'm trying to roll my own.

Example:

```
variable x = compareCriteriaBetween 3 and 6
variable y = compareCriteriaLesserThanOrEqual 5
```

The difficult part for me is finding an elegant way to compare the compareCriteria and create an intersection. In the example the intersection between the two is 'between 3 and 5'.

How can I implement this in a 'tell don't ask' manner? Note that compareCriteria can be completely unrelated (eg startsWithLetter versus betweenNumber).

Comment: You're going to have to narrow it down a bit as to what comparison criteria and domains you are talking about: in the general case, you run into mathematically undecidable statements.

Comment: Can you give me an example of such an undecidable statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have constants in your expressions you should be safe from [undecidability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems) (I think!). Problems arise as soon as you can express e.g. general statements about integers with +-*/ (see [Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_arithmetic)).

Even if you stay within the realm of decidability, there exists no algorithm that can take arbitrary statements P(x) and Q(x) and compute a statement R(x) equivalent to P(x) & Q(x) for all x, where x can range over **any** domain (integers, strings, matrices, real numbers, complex numbers, logical statements [whoops, back into undecidable territory!], ...). You need domain specific tricks to get there, and strictly delimited [languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) in which P, Q and R are formulated. There exist software products for certain domains -- one of them is called Mathematica...

Try to get back to basics: what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in simple criteria like *less equal* or *between* on integers/floats, you can rewrite *between 3 and 6* as (*greater equal 3* **and** *less equal 6*). If you combine this with a logical **and** with *less equal 5* you can use Boolean algebra to obtain (*greater equal 3* **and** (*less equal 6* **and** *less equal 5*)) before simplifying the inner parenthesis to just *less equal 5* and rewriting the result as *between 3 and 5*.